# what's the meaning of ^ in this function

Tags: machine-learning, math, statistics

Supervised learning is divided into two processes: learning and prediction, which are completed by learning system and prediction system. In the learning process, the learning system uses the given training data set to obtain a model through learning or training, which is expressed as conditional probability distribution[image] or decision function[image]

I just want to know why to add " ^ " on the top of "f(x)" or "P(Y|X)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In statistics, that symbol is used to denote an "[estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimator#Definition)" of a random variable.